# shiny-server on Fedora

Tags: r, shiny

I'm working with Shiny on a Fedora 19 box, and while I can build my applications and run them from RStudio, getting shiny-server to behave has proven trickier.  I've built shiny-server from source and have it installed such that I can start is manually easily enough.  But, once I exit the terminal window from whence I started shiny-server, it stops and my apps no longer work.

I've tried to work with systemd to create a shiny.service file and enable the service through systemctl as described here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/sTUmUL7znWg

but that failed.

How do I register shiny-server as a service that will automatically run on boot up?